# Powershell to loop over csv's and place them into a new folder using its original name

Tags: powershell, for-loop, filenames, export-csv

I've wrote out the below powershell:

```
$Headers = @(
 "Purchase Order"
  "SKU"
  "Markdown"
  "Landed Cost"
  "Original Price"
  "Current Sale Price"
  "Free Stock"
  "OPO"
  "ID Style"
  "Supplier Style No")


$Location = "\\dc1\shared\BI\HisRms"
$Destination = "C:\Users\jonathon.kindred\Desktop\RMM\"
$files = Get-ChildItem $location -Recurse -Filter "*.csv"


Foreach ($file in $files) { Select $Headers | Export-Csv Join-Path "C:\Users\jonathon.kindred\Desktop\RMM\" $_.FullName -Force -NoTypeInformation}
```

The issue i have is that it fails on all files because i am not hard coding the file path to have the .csv at the end. How do it do it so i Join-Path the $Destination and the original file name?

Comment: `Join-Path $Destination $file.Name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `foreach` loop, you can use the following:

```
Export-Csv -Path (Join-Path $Destination $file.Name) -NoType
```

[Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7) returns `FileInfo` objects when querying for files. `$files` contains those objects in your code. Each object contains properties `FullName`, `BaseName`, and `Name`. `FullName` contains the file name, the path to the file, and the extension. `BaseName` contains the name of the file without the path and extension. `Name` contains the name of the file with the extension but excludes the path.

Comment: Thanks, this has worked but its not selecting my headers & just copying over blank files, any ideas?

Comment: Outputting to CSV requires an object with properties. You can do `"" | select $headers | Export-CSV .... `